# return the smallest element in the array located in the given key

Tags: javascript

I wanted to return the smallest element in a given object and a key, but it should return undefined if the given array was empty or the property at the given key is not an array.
I solved it, but I wasn't totally satisfied with my approach.
Any suggestions to make my code shorter maybe?.

```
let obj = {
  key: [8, 5, 10, 15, 11, 21, 1, 25]
};

const smallest = (obj, key) => {
  return !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || obj[key].length <= 0 ? undefined : obj[key].reduce((l, s) => l < s ? l : s)
}
smallest(obj, 'key');
```

Comment: For backward compatibility: `Math.min.apply(Math, obj[key])`. However I wonder why you would pass something other than an array or an empty array? You have no idea of what's in `obj` before calling `smallest` maybe? I mean, this is weird to ask for the smallest number when there are no numbers at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the check and return the minimum value.

```js
const smallest = (obj, key) => Array.isArray(obj[key]) && obj[key].length
    ? Math.min(...obj[key])
    : undefined;

console.log(smallest({ key: [8, 5, 10, 15, 11, 21, 1, 25] }, 'key'));
console.log(smallest({ key: [8] }, 'key'));
console.log(smallest({ key: [] }, 'key'));
console.log(smallest({}, 'key'));
```

Comment: Hi Nina, i mean if you read my post, it requires to return ```undefined```  if the given array was empty?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reduce you can use `Math.min()` with `spread operator(...)` on the array

```js
let obj = {
  key: [8, 5, 10, 15, 11, 21, 1, 25]
};

const smallest = (obj, key) => {
  return !Array.isArray(obj[key]) || obj[key].length <= 0 ? undefined :  Math.min(...obj[key]);
}
console.log(smallest(obj, 'key'));
```

Comment: Hi,  but it should return ```undefined``` if the given array was empty